# Construction of three types of unions

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space. Let $A$ and $B$ two subsets of $X$ endowed with the subspace topology and
let
$$Y=A\cup_sB$$ where $\cup_s$ designate the union of $A$ and $B$ as sets.
and $$Y'=A'\cup_sB'$$ where  $A'=A\times \{0\}$ and $B'=B\times\{1\}$.
Consider the inclusions $$i_A:A\longrightarrow A \cup_s B$$  $$i_B:B\longrightarrow  A \cup_s B$$

Now according to theses articles : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_union_(topology)
[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_topology

We can give $Y$ the subspace topology from $X$: a set $O$ is open in $Y$ if $O=Y\cap U$ where $U$ is any open subset of $X$. we will denote $Y_s$ the set $Y$ endowed with this subspace topology.

We can give $Y$ the coherent topology: a set $O$ is open in $Y$ if $i_A^{-1}(O)\cap A$ is open in $A$ and $ i_B^{-1}(O)\cap B$ is open in $B$. We will denote $Y_c$ the set $Y$ endowed with this coherent topology.

We can give $Y'$ the disjoint union topology: a set $O'$ is open in $Y'$ if $O'\cap A'$ is open in $A'$ and $ O'\cap B'$ is open in $B'$.

The point is that when $A$ and $B$ are disjoint as sets then $Y_c$ and $Y'$ are different as sets but they  will be homeomorphic as topological spaces, in particular $Y_c$ and $Y'$ will be both disconnected.

But if the sets $A$ and $B$ are not disjoint as sets, then $Y_c$ and $Y'$ are different as sets and are also topologically different, for example $Y'$ is always disconnected as a set union of two disjoint and open subsets $A'$ and $B'$ while $Y_c$ need not be disconnected as $A$ and $B$ are not disjoint.

Is my reasoning correct? thank you for your help!

Comment: In the last paragraph, $Y_c$ and $Y'$ *may* be topologically different (and in fact *may* already differ in cardinality), but in some cases they are homeomorphic

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Thank you Hagen! what is cardinality here?

Comment: the number of elements of a set

Comment: E.g. we can take $A$ having 3 points, $B$ having $4$ and intersection of size 2. Then the coherent union has 5 elements, the disjoint union has 7. So they’re trivially non-homeomorphic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Y_s$ also has a nice characterisation as the *minimal* topology that makes $i_A$ and $i_B$ continuous. We don’t really need these maps to describe the coherent topology $Y_c$: we can just say $$O \subseteq Y_c \text{ is open } \iff O \cap A \text{ is open in } A \text{ and } O \cap B \text{ is open in } B$$ and this makes it the *largest* topology that makes $i_A$ and $i_B$ continuous. So these topologies are the extremes of the topologies we can put on the set $A \cup B$. To describe the topology on $Y’$ we need to define injections $j_A: A \to A’$ by $j_A(a)=(a,0)$ and $j_B: B \to B’$ by $j_B(b)=(b,1)$ and the topology on $Y’$ is then again the *largest* one that makes $j_A,j_B$ continuous. This makes the analogy between $Y_s$ and $Y’$ more clear I think.

If $A$ and $B$ are disjoint to start with, it’s clear that $Y_c \simeq Y’$, but the coherent topology is most often applied when the union we take is not disjoint (and often infinite). If $A,B$ are both closed and $A \cup B = X$, the coherent topology on $X$ is just $X$ itself and $X’$ (as a disjoint union) is non-connected so it’s quite easy to create non-homeomorphic examples for $X$ connected when $A,B$ are necessarily overlapping.

So your reasoning is mostly correct but can be slightly refined.